# What makes a "production code"?

Tags: production-environment, production

I am a Research Scientist, and definitely the way we code is not considered "production code" that's prototypical code, but then what makes a production code ?
Testing for scalability, ability to handle real time traffic and testing all edge cases ?
But what else, for instance I also hear Python is less of a "production language" that Java or C#, what is the criteria for them to be production-able.

Any books/references drawing this point home or to sublime it, would also be great!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Production code generally means its ready to ship out to a client.

1. Most obvious bugs are fixed
2. code is well-structured and [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code)
3. Automated Tests are written and have a sufficient level of coverage
4. It's gone through a peer review process before being incorporated into the main code base.
5. It will pass the ["build system"](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Edww4s/articles/build_systems.html) may automatically check rules like: coding conventions, complexity, linting, testing, compilation. Sometimes this may include deployment success to a testing environment.

### How would this compare to non-production code?

Nearly all developers start with prototype/non-production code, even developers that use Test Driven Development (TDD). The goal of their code is to "just make this work" so they can develop a first pass approach to a problem. Often this will lead to poorly named variables, excessively long (number of commands) functions, improperly formatted and often little or no tests.

Once a developer has a satisfactory working solution, they go back and clean up the code. They fix spelling errors; use [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), if they see one that's helpful; they make their code fit the teams coding conventions and style guide, some of which lead to real heated debates on using [tabs vs spaces](https://www.businessinsider.com/tabs-vs-spaces-from-silicon-valley-2016-5).

#### The best way to think about it is:

The first pass at writing code is a software draft that is to get the developers ideas on the page until they have their "Story" or functionality set. The goal is for them to understand it.

The second pass, i.e., getting it ready for production is refining it so that other people can understand their code. In paper writing terms, you're giving it a more coherent structure and improve trying to convey your meaning to other people better.

### That's not all.

While this will generally apply to writing code, part of saying something is "ready for production" is including all the steps not involved with the actual application code.

Often it's all the steps needed to get the code into the clients hands or live.

This could be creating a [Continuous Integration](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/continuous-integration/) and [Continuous Deployment](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/continuous-deployment/) system. Setting up servers, deployment groups, monitoring systems and so on.

Without these things your application may not be considered production ready by your organization.

Comment: Really love this answer! Working on my  own fullstack project and as it has grown, my anxiety has exponentially grown about what problems could be lurking in the shadows. Tried TDD but that was a huge waste of time as I spent a month writing tests only to completely change my database tables and have to throw the tests away. Anyway, do you have any tips that you follow to at least make the first-pass more robust or do things eventually work out in the end after all the tests?

Comment: I mean if you're just working on a personal hobby project (as a new developer) then don't worry as much about tests because you're trying to learn the language and get your bearings. 

In enterprise environments, tests are a MUST. When you write your tests there are limits on what you should be testing. you shouldnt be testing third party libraries (that's their job), you should also be working with mocks. In your case, if you designed your code with robust ORMs and repository pattern changing schema or even database type shouldn't be a big deal. It means you had too tight of an integration.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the tips. Will definitely cut myself some slack and focus on getting to grips with the languages and frameworks. I'm building an online store for a friend. Pretty far along now but it's a verrry large bowl of spaghetti code at this point. Definitely resonate with the idea of iterating over the system a couple times to perfect it.