# What is OAuthlib's HTTPS verification?

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I was using the YouTube Data API and it said the following:

```
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
```

What is meant here by production and OAuthlib's HTTPS verification?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official docs of `OAuthLib` library, the meaning of the environment variable `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` is as follows:

> [**`OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT`**](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/security.html#envvar-OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT)
>
> Normally, OAuthLib will raise an `InsecureTransportError` if you attempt to use OAuth2 over HTTP, rather than HTTPS. Setting this environment variable will prevent this error from being raised. This is mostly useful for local testing, or automated tests. *Never* set this variable in production.

Thus, having `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` set within the environment of your running app will allow you to issue OAuth2 calls through HTTP.

As the doc says, you should never have `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` set on production settings, i.e. on settings that enable your program to run for real, for example on your client's sites -- these settings considered as opposed to the settings that are under your complete control, such as those that enable your program to be tested before deployment to your clients.

(You may also read [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009324/8327971) here on SO.)